# Why TextWriterTraceListener can't work in release mode?

Tags: c#, trace, release-mode, debug-mode

This program can work on debug mode but can't work on release mode:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Trace.Listeners.Add(new TextWriterTraceListener(@"c:\prog\a.txt"));
        Debug.AutoFlush = true;
        Debug.WriteLine("abc");
        Debug.Close();
    }
```

When this program run in release mode,it can work without error,but can't write line "abc" in a.txt
Can you teach me why?Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by can't work? Do you get any error or something like that? Please provide more information.

Comment: There is no error,but the prog can't write "abc" in a.txt when using realse mode

Comment: You're using Debug to write to it, and Debug doesn't work in release mode. It's meant to write things you don't want to see in release mode. Use `Trace.WriteLine` and it'll work.

Comment: Thanks...I make a naive mistake...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using

```
Debug.WriteLine("abc")
```

Which will not compile when building in release mode, use instead :

```
Trace.WriteLine("abc")
```

Note also that `Trace` wil execute on both modes of building.